# How can I delete indexes including multiple conditions?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I try to delete specified indexes which meet the chosen conditions.

At the moment I delete them using one condition like shown below

```
localhost:9200/pictures/picture/_delete_by_query?pretty
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
                "tag": ".*something.*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to delete them for instance in this way

```
localhost:9200/pictures/picture/_delete_by_query?pretty
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
                "tag": ".*something.*",
                "path": "this/is/my/path",
                "user_id": 2,

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: Is `path` and `user_id` exact values and not regex? Also please share the mapping of your index.

Comment: @NishantSaini Yes, `path` and `user_id` are the exact values. However I would be grateful if you could also show example including `path` and `user_id` as a regexp. But it is not as important as the first example. I added mapping of my index to the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I guess using a bool query would be the right direction, something like this should work:

```
localhost:9200/pictures/picture/_delete_by_query?pretty
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "regexp":{
                            "tag": ".*something.*",
                            "path": "this/is/my/path",
                            "user_id": 2,

                        }
                    }               
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "path.keyword": "this/is/my/path"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "user_id.keyword": 2
                    }               
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```